# JQuery MagicLine Navigation to dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I’m using the magic line in one of my projects. It works perfectly except with some of the dropdown elements. When I click some dropdowns, it resets to the end of the page. Ideally I’d like to have it stay above the parent navigation.

i am using a bootstrap dropdown menu.

HTML Code:

```
 <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
        <ul id="navigation" class="nav navbar-nav" style="position:relative;">
          <li class="dropdown"> <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" href="#">About<b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                    <li><a href="#" >Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" >Investors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Board</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="#" >Culture</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
           <li class="dropdown"> <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" href="#">Products<b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">All Spark</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" >Engage</a></li>
             </ul>
            </li>
 </ul></div>
```

Js code:

```
$(function() {
/* Add Magic Line markup via JavaScript, because it ain't gonna work without */
$("#navigation").append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
/* Cache it */

var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

$magicLine
    .width($(".active").width())
    .css("left", $(".active a").position().left)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

$("#navigation li").find("a").hover(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    leftPos = $el.position().left;
    newWidth = $el.parent().width();

    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: leftPos,
        width: newWidth
    });
}, function() {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
        width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
    });    
});
});
```

CSS Code:

```
#magic-line { position: absolute; bottom: -4px; left: 0;  height: 4px; background: #fff; opacity:0; width:68px !important;}

#navigation li:hover ~ #magic-line, #navigation li.op ~ #magic-line{ opacity:1;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. The reason behind this issue is ,all bootstrap li in navbar is `Position:relative`, but magic menus li must be in `Position:static`.

How I solved this:

I set all `li` into `position:static`:

```
 .nav > li{position:static}
```

Then I add this css:

```
.nav > li .open{position:relative}
```

This will do.

Comment: Your answer is ok, but if you have a new question, ask this as a separate question. Here (to the answers) you should only write your answer *to the original question*.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Asm's changes I also edited the line

```
$("#navigation li").find("a").hover(function() {
```

to

```
$("#navigation>li").hover(function() {
```